# git binaries installed from debian package

Tags: debian, shell, git

I have installed git on Debian 10.

Why do I have two identical git binaries in two different places?

```
/usr/lib/git-core/git
/usr/bin/git
```

These are identical files, have same sha256sum. But they are not hardlinks.
They are same files existing in two copies.

Seems strange. I wonder what's the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particularity has been [upsetting some for years](https://bugs.debian.org/700839).
BTW, you'll read as part of the answer from Jonathan Nieder that [upstream does hardlink](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Makefile) but Debian does not ship that way since they can't be sure both path are on the same filesystem.
[ArchLinux faced this problem years ago](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/13683?opened=4539&status%5B0%5D=).